# scaling logo in html5 <canvas>?

Tags: html, canvas

Having trouble scaling with .  It seems to make sense to code up a drawing in canvas to a fixed size (ie 800x600) then scale it for specific locations - but sizing occurs in 4 places: 1) in the context definition (ie ctx.width = 800  2) with ctx.scale;  3) in html with

I can scale it with ctx.scale(0.25,0.25) and use  but this doesn't appear right - it seems to want the scale to be proportional.

css sizing simply makes it fuzzy so not a good way to go.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can resize a canvas using stylesheets. The results may vary across browsers as  HTML5 is still in the process of being finalized.

There is no `width` or `height` property for a drawing context, only for canvas. A context's `scale` is used to resize the unit step size in `x` or `y` dimensions and it doesn't have to be proportional. For example,

```
context.scale(5, 1);
```

changes the `x` unit size to 5, and y's to 1. If we draw a 30x30 square now, it will actually come out to be 150x30 as `x` has been scaled 5 times while `y` remains the same. If you want the logo to be larger, increase the context scale **before** drawing your logo.

Mozilla has a good tutorial on [scaling and transformations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Transformations) in general.

**Edit**: In response to your comment, the logo's size and canvas dimensions will determine what should be the scaling factor for enlarging the image. If the logo is 100x100 px in size and the canvas is 800x600, then you are limited by canvas height (600) as its smaller. So the maximum scaling that you can do without clipping part of the logo outside canvas will be 600/100 = 6

```
context.scale(6, 6)
```

These numbers will vary and you can do your own calculations to find the optimal size.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the logo to svg and let the browser do the scaling for you, with or without adding css mediaqueries.

Check out Andreas Bovens' [presentation and examples](http://my.opera.com/ODIN/blog/2009/10/12/how-media-queries-allow-you-to-optimize-svg-icons-for-several-sizes).

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the image when you draw it

```
imageobject=new Image();
imageobject.src="imagefile";
imageobject.onload=function(){
    context.drawImage(imageobject,0,0,imageobject.width,imageobject.height,0,0,800,600);
}
```

The last 2 arguments are the width an height to resize the image

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-drawimage

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `element.style.width` and `element.style.height` attributes (assuming element is a canvas element)  you are stretching the contents of the canvas.  If you set the `element.width` and `element.height` you are resizing the canvas itself not the content.  The `ctx.scale` is for dynamic resizing whenever you drawing something with javascript and gives you the same stretching effect as `element.style`.